# Detecting utf8 broken characters in MySQL

Tags: mysql, utf-8

I've got a database with a bunch of broken utf8 characters scattered across several tables.
The list of characters isn't very extensive AFAIK (áéíúóÁÉÍÓÚÑñ)

Fixing a given table is very straightforward

```
update orderItem set itemName=replace(itemName,'Ã¡','á');
```

But I can't get a way of detecting the broken characters. If I do something like

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE field LIKE "%Ã%";
```

I get nearly all the fields because of the collation (Ã=a). All broken characters so far start with an "Ã". The database is in spanish so this particular character isn't used

The list of broken chars I've got so far is

```
Ã¡ = á
Ã© = é
Ã­- = í
Ã³ = ó
Ã± = ñ
Ã¡ = Á
```

Any idea of how to make this SELECT to work as intended? (a binary search or something like that)

Comment: Are you sure you’re using UTF-8? Those “broken characters” seem as you’re interpreting UTF-8 encoded data with ISO 8859-1. Because the character `á` is encoded with UTF-8 as 0xC3A1 and that represents the characters `Ã` and `¡` in ISO 8859-1.

Comment: Don't look at me. My work is to fix this db. I didn't broke it.

Comment: This is called "Mojibake" and is discussed [_here_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about a different approach, namely converting the column back and forth to get the correct character set? You can convert it to binary, then to utf-8 and then to iso-8859-1 or whatever else you're using. See the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-conversion.html) for the details.

Comment: the idea is to end up whit a utf-8 encoded db. right now the encoding a collation is utf-8 general. but apparently the application that use the db was interpreting as ISO8859.
If I convert it back and forth, I will end with the same data...

Comment: well, only converting back and forth doesn't do magic, the characters stills broken. BUT in binary I can make a select looking for the Ã character. So now I have a mechanism to detect the broken chars. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, I remain convinced that there must be a way to use the conversion mechanism in a more general way but it might be more complex than first stated. Happy you found a solution that worked.

Comment: If you mess up when altering column type, you may lose data. Instead with UPDATE queries, you can run UPDATE queries inside [a transaction](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html), check the result, and commit only if this is ok or rollback if not.

Answer (score 88):

I fixed with

```
UPDATE wp_zcs9ck_posts_copy SET post_title = 
    CONVERT(BINARY CONVERT(post_title USING latin1) USING utf8);
```

Complete solution: http://jonisalonen.com/2012/fixing-doubly-utf-8-encoded-text-in-mysql/

Comment: Backup your database first... this deleted everything but the first half sentence in my wp_posts -> post_content field!

Comment: Worked for me as well. Consider using `SELECT name, CONVERT(BINARY CONVERT(name USING latin1) USING utf8) AS conv FROM table WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM table WHERE LENGTH(name) != CHAR_LENGTH(name));` to find broken records and see the result before using `UPDATE`.

Comment: I made unnecessary subquery in the comment above. Use this `SELECT name, CONVERT(BINARY CONVERT(name USING latin1) USING utf8) AS conv FROM table WHERE LENGTH(name) != CHAR_LENGTH(name)` instead

Comment: This answer applies to double-encoding, not simple Mojibake.

Comment: I have found that checking if CONVERT(BINARY CONVERT(bundle_display_name USING latin1) USING utf8) is not NULL before doing the update helps preventing already correctly encoded values getting broken (the test with length/char_length doesn't work well as "Ã©" will be 3/1 but it's correct value "é" is still 2/1)

Answer (score 41):

```
UPDATE `table_name` SET `column_name` = REPLACE(`column_name` ,'Ã¡','á');
UPDATE `table_name` SET `column_name` = REPLACE(`column_name` ,'Ã¤','ä');
UPDATE `table_name` SET `column_name` = REPLACE(`column_name` ,'Ã©','é');
UPDATE `table_name` SET `column_name` = REPLACE(`column_name` ,'í©','é');
UPDATE `table_name` SET `column_name` = REPLACE(`column_name` ,'Ã³','ó');
UPDATE `table_name` SET `column_name` = REPLACE(`column_name` ,'íº','ú');
UPDATE `table_name` SET `column_name` = REPLACE(`column_name` ,'Ãº','ú');
UPDATE `table_name` SET `column_name` = REPLACE(`column_name` ,'Ã±','ñ');
UPDATE `table_name` SET `column_name` = REPLACE(`column_name` ,'í‘','Ñ');
UPDATE `table_name` SET `column_name` = REPLACE(`column_name` ,'Ã','í');
UPDATE `table_name` SET `column_name` = REPLACE(`column_name` ,'â€“','–');
UPDATE `table_name` SET `column_name` = REPLACE(`column_name`,'â€™','\'');
UPDATE `table_name` SET `column_name` = REPLACE(`column_name`,'â€¦','...');
UPDATE `table_name` SET `column_name` = REPLACE(`column_name`,'â€“','-');
UPDATE `table_name` SET `column_name` = REPLACE(`column_name`,'â€œ','"');
UPDATE `table_name` SET `column_name` = REPLACE(`column_name`,'â€','"');
UPDATE `table_name` SET `column_name` = REPLACE(`column_name`,'â€˜','\'');
UPDATE `table_name` SET `column_name` = REPLACE(`column_name`,'â€¢','-');
UPDATE `table_name` SET `column_name` = REPLACE(`column_name`,'â€¡','c');
UPDATE `table_name` SET `column_name` = REPLACE(`column_name` ,'Â','');
```

Comment: What about processing the .sql file with a scripting language like Perl and replace all the "wrong" characters? In Perl it can be easily done with something like this: $content =~ s/Ã¡/á/g; Repeat the same sentence for the rest of the characters. $content is a string storing the whole file.

Comment: This worked for me, though I had a totally different character set, so had to do every character manually using Adam Lynch's trick(http://stackoverflow.com/a/6112241/807104), Only had to run queries 409 times, 'So I got that goin for me which is nice'.

Comment: I've been trying to update a number of tables from other datasources for weeks using more comprehensive methods but this is by far the easiest. thanks! Was assembling this info myself today.

Answer (score 23):

Thanks for your answers!!

I fixed my tables with this, and wanted to share the full list of changes. Note that it also includes fixing html decoded characters, besides latin ones, it was really a mess:

(If you need more conversions, look them up at https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl)

```
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'â€', '"');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'â€“', '–');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'â€¢', '-');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'â€œ', '"');

update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Â¡', '¡');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Â¢', '¢');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Â£', '£');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Â¤', '¤');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Â¥', '¥');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Â¦', '¦');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Â§', '§');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Â¨', '¨');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Â©', '©');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Âª', 'ª');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Â«', '«');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Â¬', '¬');
# This one looks like it's missing a character, but it's there. 0xad
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Â­', '­');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Â®', '®');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Â¯', '¯');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Â°', '°');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Â±', '±');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Â²', '²');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Â³', '³');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Â´', '´');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Âµ', 'µ');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Â¶', '¶');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Â·', '·');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Â¸', '¸');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Â¹', '¹');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Âº', 'º');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Â»', '»');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Â¼', '¼');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Â½', '½');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Â¾', '¾');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Â¿', '¿');

update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Ã€', 'À');
# This one looks like it's missing a character, but it's there. 0x81
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Ã', 'Á');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Ã‚', 'Â');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Ãƒ', 'Ã');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Ã„', 'Ä');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Ã…', 'Å');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Ã†', 'Æ');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Ã‡', 'Ç');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Ãˆ', 'È');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Ã‰', 'É');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'ÃŠ', 'Ê');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Ã‹', 'Ë');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'ÃŒ', 'Ì');
# This one looks like it's missing a character, but it's there. 0x8d
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Ã', 'Í');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'ÃŽ', 'Î');
# This one looks like it's missing a character, but it's there. 0x8f
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Ã', 'Ï');
# This one looks like it's missing a character, but it's there. 0x90
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Ã', 'Ð');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Ã‘', 'Ñ');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Ã’', 'Ò');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Ã“', 'Ó');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Ã”', 'Ô');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Ã•', 'Õ');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Ã–', 'Ö');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Ã—', '×');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Ã˜', 'Ø');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Ã™', 'Ù');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Ãš', 'Ú');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Ã›', 'Û');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Ãœ', 'Ü');
# This one looks like it's missing a character, but it's there. 0x9d
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Ã', 'Ý');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Ãž', 'Þ');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'ÃŸ', 'ß');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Ã ', 'à');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Ã¡', 'á');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Ã¢', 'â');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Ã£', 'ã');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Ã¤', 'ä');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Ã¥', 'å');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Ã¦', 'æ');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Ã§', 'ç');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Ã¨', 'è');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Ã©', 'é');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Ãª', 'ê');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Ã«', 'ë');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Ã¬', 'ì');
# This one looks like it's missing a character, but it's there. 0xad
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, '­­Ã', 'í');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Ã®', 'î');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Ã¯', 'ï');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Ã°', 'ð');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Ã±', 'ñ');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Ã²', 'ò');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Ã³', 'ó');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Ã´', 'ô');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Ãµ', 'õ');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Ã¶', 'ö');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Ã·', '÷');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Ã¸', 'ø');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Ã¹', 'ù');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Ãº', 'ú');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Ã»', 'û');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Ã¼', 'ü');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Ã½', 'ý');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Ã¾', 'þ');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field`, 'Ã¿', 'ÿ');

update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&ccedil;','ç');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&atilde;','ã');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&aacute;','á');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&acirc;','â');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&eacute;','é');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&iacute;','í');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&otilde;','õ');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&uacute;','ú');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&ccedil;','ç');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&Aacute;','Á');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&Acirc;','Â');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&Eacute;','É');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&Iacute;','Í');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&Otilde;','Õ');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&Uacute;','Ú');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&Ccedil;','Ç');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&Atilde;','Ã');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&Agrave;','À');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&Ecirc;','Ê');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&Oacute;','Ó');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&Ocirc;','Ô');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&Uuml;','Ü');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&atilde;','ã');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&agrave;','à');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&ecirc;','ê');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&oacute;','ó');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&ocirc;','ô');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&uuml;','ü');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&amp;','&');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&gt;','>');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&lt;','<');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&circ;','ˆ');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&tilde;','˜');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&uml;','¨');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&cute;','´');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&cedil;','¸');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&quot;','"');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&ldquo;','“');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&rdquo;','”');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&lsquo;','‘');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&rsquo;','’');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&lsaquo;','‹');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&rsaquo;','›');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&laquo;','«');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&raquo;','»');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&ordm;','º');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&ordf;','ª');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&ndash;','–');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&mdash;','—');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&macr;','¯');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&hellip;','…');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&brvbar;','¦');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&bull;','•');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&para;','¶');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&sect;','§');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&sup1;','¹');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&sup2;','²');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&sup3;','³');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&frac12;','½');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&frac14;','¼');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&frac34;','¾');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&#8539;','⅛');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&#8540;','⅜');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&#8541;','⅝');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&#8542;','⅞');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&gt;','>');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&lt;','<');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&plusmn;','±');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&minus;','−');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&times;','×');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&divide;','÷');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&lowast;','∗');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&frasl;','⁄');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&permil;','‰');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&int;','∫');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&sum;','∑');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&prod;','∏');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&radic;','√');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&infin;','∞');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&asymp;','≈');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&cong;','≅');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&prop;','∝');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&equiv;','≡');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&ne;','≠');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&le;','≤');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&ge;','≥');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&there4;','∴');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&sdot;','⋅');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&middot;','·');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&part;','∂');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&image;','ℑ');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&real;','ℜ');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&prime;','′');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&Prime;','″');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&deg;','°');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&ang;','∠');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&perp;','⊥');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&nabla;','∇');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&oplus;','⊕');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&otimes;','⊗');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&alefsym;','ℵ');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&oslash;','ø');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&Oslash;','Ø');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&isin;','∈');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&notin;','∉');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&cap;','∩');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&cup;','∪');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&sub;','⊂');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&sup;','⊃');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&sube;','⊆');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&supe;','⊇');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&exist;','∃');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&forall;','∀');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&empty;','∅');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&not;','¬');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&and;','∧');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&or;','∨');
update `table` set `field` = replace(`field` ,'&crarr;','↵');
```

Comment: That was the only solution that worked to me! The binary thing didnt work, even in a SELECT. Thanx!

Comment: This is a great list but the ordering is problematic because by the time the search for "â€¢" occurs for example, the â€ part at the beginning will have been replaced.

Answer (score 17):

No text replacement is a universal solutions because you can forget some character.
A more suitable **fix for double converted characters** is:

1. convert back to latin1
2. convert to binary
3. convert to utf8

Like this:

```
alter table descriptions modify name VARCHAR(2000) character set latin1;
alter table descriptions modify name blob;
alter table descriptions modify name VARCHAR(2000) character set utf8;
```

Comment: Though now I detected that it didn't work completely.  Text that had a ' character was cut off at that character after the 3 alter table commands.  :-(

Comment: This answer worked well for me. I added a simple script to my class collection, which will do this for all tables in a database. Instruction can be found here: http://www.os-cms.net/blog/view/34/Fix-utf8-broken-characters-in-MySQL Just if someone would find it useful.

Comment: This truncated columns data where non UTF 8 characters present and chinese characters replaced with question marks - Not a good solution for ones don't want to lose data.

Comment: Shorter to do it in 2 steps:   `ALTER TABLE tbl MODIFY COLUMN col VARBINARY(111) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE tbl MODIFY COLUMN col VARCHAR(111) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NOT NULL;`

Comment: Wow. This is awesome. Save me a lot of headache. Would be nice to have a script that does this to all varchar columns in all tables inside a db.

Answer (score 16):

The `SELECT` statement you need is the following:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE LENGTH(name) != CHAR_LENGTH(name);
```

This returns all rows which contain multi-byte characters.

`name` is assumed to be a field / the field where weird characters would be found. *

Answer (score 16):

This saved my life

```
UPDATE ohp_posts SET post_content = CONVERT(CAST(CONVERT(post_content USING latin1) AS BINARY) USING utf8)
```

I've found it here http://stanis.net/2014/04/replacing-latin-1-with-utf-8-characters-in-mysql/

Answer (score 7):

To convert all latin characters to correct accents try this on MySQL :

```
UPDATE your_table SET your_column = CONVERT(CAST(CONVERT(your_column USING latin1) AS BINARY) USING utf8)
```

Answer (score 3):

I had this same problem but didn't like the replace() solution because there's always the possibility of missing some characters. I was working against a column with mixed data (some had been utf8_encode()d and some not) with 4 million or so rows, about 250k records with mis-encoded data (with Ã‰/etc characters), covering about 15 international languages, including mainly European languages but also Russian, Japanese and Chinese.

I started by duplicating the column, since I didn't want to lose any data:

```
ALTER TABLE images ADD COLUMN reptitle TEXT;
```

Copied all the data with multibyte characters (thanks Adam for the tip)

```
UPDATE images SET reptitle = title WHERE LENGTH(title) != CHAR_LENGTH(title)
```

Since reptitle was created with the table's default character set it was already utf8, but contained the corrupted data since images table used to be a latin source.
Column reptitle now contains some data which is correctly encoded, and some corrupted (all values with multibyte characters, some had been correctly utf8_encode()d. So then with David's tip...

```
ALTER TABLE images MODIFY reptitle TEXT character set latin1;
ALTER TABLE images MODIFY reptitle BLOB;
ALTER TABLE images MODIFY reptitle TEXT character set utf8;
```

The middle step may not have been necessary since TEXT and BLOB (I think) are the same.
This had the effect of correcting all incorrectly encoded data ('Ã©tudiantes' became 'étudiantes', etc) but data which was previously correct was truncated at the first multibyte character ('Lapin de Pâques' became 'Lapin de P'). I don't know why the truncation, but it's in a disposable column so I didn't care.
The truncated data gives CHAR_LENGTH and LENGTH of the same values because there are no multi-byte characters remaining so easy query...

```
UPDATE images SET title = reptitle WHERE LENGTH(reptitle)!=CHAR_LENGTH(reptitle)
```

Then of course just drop the spare column

```
ALTER TABLE images DROP COLUMN reptitle
```

Also make sure (since I use PHP and this had tripped me up a couple of times so I thought I'd mention it here) all your script files are UTF8 (without BOM) and you are using:

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8', $connection);
```

Et voilà... perfectly repaired data, all languages :)

Comment: Thanks for this - the method of adding a column and then copying them across is a good one, and laying it out like this is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Raúl Avila Solano and acseven's answer if you want to **update all the broken characters in one query** you can do:

```
update `table` set field = replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(field,'&uuml;','ü'),'&ocirc;','ô'),'&oacute;','ó'),'&ecirc;','ê'),'&agrave;','à'),'&atilde;','ã'),'&Uuml;','Ü'),'&Ocirc;','Ô'),'&Oacute;','Ó'),'&Ecirc;','Ê'),'&Agrave;','À'),'&Atilde;','Ã'),'&Ccedil;','Ç'),'&Uacute;','Ú'),'&Otilde;','Õ'),'&Iacute;','Í'),'&Iacute;','Í'),'&Eacute;','É'),'&Acirc;','Â'),'&Aacute;','Á'),'&ccedil;','ç'),'&uacute;','ú'),'&otilde;','õ'),'&iacute;','í'),'&eacute;','é'),'&acirc;','â'),'&aacute;','á'),'&atilde;','ã'),'&ccedil;','ç'),'Ã ','à'),'Ã ','à'),'Âº','º'),'Âª','ª'),'Ã§','ç'),'â€“','–'),'Ã³','ó'),'Ã©','é'),'Ã¡','á'),'Ãª','ê'),'Ã£','ã'),'Ã¢','â'),'Ã­','í'),'Ãµ','õ'),'Ã˜','Ø'),'â€¢','-'),'Ãº','ú'),'Ã ','À'),'Ãƒ','Ã'),'Ã‡','Ç'),'â€','"'),'â€œ','"'),'Ã‰','É');
```

Answer (score 2):

this also solved my problem on some italian chars

```
UPDATE `table_name` SET `column_name` = REPLACE(`column_name` ,'Ã¡','á');
UPDATE `table_name` SET `column_name` = REPLACE(`column_name` ,'Ã¤','ä');
UPDATE `table_name` SET `column_name` = REPLACE(`column_name` ,'Ã©','é');
UPDATE `table_name` SET `column_name` = REPLACE(`column_name` ,'í©','é');
UPDATE `table_name` SET `column_name` = REPLACE(`column_name` ,'Ã³','ó');
UPDATE `table_name` SET `column_name` = REPLACE(`column_name` ,'íº','ú');
UPDATE `table_name` SET `column_name` = REPLACE(`column_name` ,'Ãº','ú');
UPDATE `table_name` SET `column_name` = REPLACE(`column_name` ,'Ã±','ñ');
UPDATE `table_name` SET `column_name` = REPLACE(`column_name` ,'í‘','Ñ');
UPDATE `table_name` SET `column_name` = REPLACE(`column_name` ,'Ã','í');
UPDATE `table_name` SET `column_name` = REPLACE(`column_name` ,'â€“','–');
UPDATE `table_name` SET `column_name` = REPLACE(`column_name`,'â€™','\'');
UPDATE `table_name` SET `column_name` = REPLACE(`column_name`,'â€¦','...');
UPDATE `table_name` SET `column_name` = REPLACE(`column_name`,'â€“','-');
UPDATE `table_name` SET `column_name` = REPLACE(`column_name`,'â€œ','"');
UPDATE `table_name` SET `column_name` = REPLACE(`column_name`,'â€','"');
UPDATE `table_name` SET `column_name` = REPLACE(`column_name`,'â€˜','\'');
UPDATE `table_name` SET `column_name` = REPLACE(`column_name`,'â€¢','-');
UPDATE `table_name` SET `column_name` = REPLACE(`column_name`,'â€¡','c');
UPDATE `table_name` SET `column_name` = REPLACE(`column_name` ,'Â','');
UPDATE `table_name` SET `column_name` = REPLACE(`column_name` ,'í ','à');
UPDATE `table_name` SET `column_name` = REPLACE(`column_name` ,'í¨','è');
UPDATE `table_name` SET `column_name` = REPLACE(`column_name` ,'íˆ','È');
UPDATE `table_name` SET `column_name` = REPLACE(`column_name` ,'â‚¬','€');
UPDATE `table_name` SET `column_name` = REPLACE(`column_name` ,'eÌ€','è');
UPDATE `table_name` SET `column_name` = REPLACE(`column_name` ,'í²','ò');
UPDATE `table_name` SET `column_name` = REPLACE(`column_name` ,'í¹','ù');
```

Answer (score 2):

You might have rows with properly encoded UTF8 and with wrongly encoded characters. In this case "CONVERT(BINARY CONVERT(post_title USING latin1) USING utf8)" will trim some fields.

I ended up doing it this way

```
update `table` set `name` = replace(`name` ,CONVERT(BINARY "ä" USING latin1),'ä');
update `table` set `name` = replace(`name` ,CONVERT(BINARY "ö" USING latin1),'ö');
update `table` set `name` = replace(`name` ,CONVERT(BINARY "ü" USING latin1),'ü');
update `table` set `name` = replace(`name` ,CONVERT(BINARY "Ä" USING latin1),'Ä');
update `table` set `name` = replace(`name` ,CONVERT(BINARY "Ö" USING latin1),'Ö');
update `table` set `name` = replace(`name` ,CONVERT(BINARY "Ü" USING latin1),'Ü');
update `table` set `name` = replace(`name` ,CONVERT(BINARY "ß" USING latin1),'ß');
```

Comment: This helped me so much! :3 Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is an extension of  @Thales Ceolin's answer in order to modify every table in the db:

```
select concat(
    "update ", 
    a.TABLE_NAME, 
    " set ", b.COLUMN_NAME, 
    " = CONVERT(BINARY CONVERT(", 
    b.COLUMN_NAME, 
    " USING latin1) USING utf8) where ",
    b.COLUMN_NAME, 
    " is not null;") query
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES a
left join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS b on a.TABLE_NAME = b.TABLE_NAME
where a.table_schema = 'db_name'
and a.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
and b.data_type in ('text', 'varchar')
and a.TABLE_NAME = 'table_name';
```

This will result in:

```
update table_name set idn = CONVERT(BINARY CONVERT(idn USING latin1) USING utf8) where idn is not null;
update table_nameset name = CONVERT(BINARY CONVERT(name USING latin1) USING utf8) where name is not null;
update table_name set primary_last_name = CONVERT(BINARY CONVERT(primary_last_name USING latin1) USING utf8) where primary_last_name is not null;
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on data in this post https://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html I'd suggest this is a good query of identifying dodgy entries and possible correct values:

`SELECT my_field,CONVERT(BINARY CONVERT(my_field USING latin1) USING utf8mb4) AS new_field_value FROM my_table WHERE my_field REGEXP '[âÆËÅÂÃ]';`

Be very careful because we had a bad encoding of a file name, but an OK encoding of the path, and in that case some of the solutions above would have caused a world of pain. If some of your data is already correctly encoded in UTF8 you'll likely find you lost a chunk of it.

Answer (score 0):

The middle step may not have been necessary since `TEXT` and `BLOB` are the same.

This had the effect of correcting all incorrectly encoded data but data which was previously correct was truncated at the first multibyte character.

Answer (score 0):

As the main question was on detecting broken chars my solution:
(To prevent normal charset double encoding)

1. Detection ( latin1 to utf8 )

```
SELECT name FROM %table% 
 WHERE 
CONVERT(CONVERT(name USING BINARY) USING utf8 ) != CONVERT(CONVERT(CONVERT(CONVERT(name USING BINARY) USING latin1) USING BINARY) USING utf8);
```

2. Update( latin1 to utf8 )

```
UPDATE %table% SET name = convert(cast(convert(name using latin1 ) as binary) using utf8 )
 WHERE 
CONVERT(CONVERT(name USING BINARY) USING utf8 ) != CONVERT(CONVERT(CONVERT(CONVERT(name USING BINARY) USING latin1) USING BINARY) USING utf8);
```

Answer (score 0):

This query helped me identify rows that had bad characters in them.
Basically you identify where the field isn't null, then convert to UTF8 and check for null after conversion.

```
select ach.*
from ach_warehouse ach
where addendum is not null and convert(addendum using utf8) is null;
```