# How to fix broken encoded characters in a latin1 encoded column

Tags: mysql, encoding, utf-8, latin1

I have a latin1 table that was filled with different encoded data for a long time so it contains a lot of broken characters. I was trying to fix that and [How to detect UTF-8 characters in a Latin1 encoded column - MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304485/how-to-detect-utf-8-characters-in-a-latin1-encoded-column-mysql) to be very helpful, especially the following code

```
SELECT CONVERT(CONVERT(name USING BINARY) USING latin1) AS latin1, CONVERT(CONVERT(name USING BINARY) USING utf8) AS utf8 FROM users WHERE CONVERT(name USING BINARY) RLIKE CONCAT('[', UNHEX('80'), '-', UNHEX('FF'), ']')
```

but this does not fix all the issues.
The ä character displayed as "Ã¤" is converted back to ä with that command, but I also have some ä characters showing up as "Â„" so it seems a different encoding format was used, but I have no idea which one that was so I could revert it. I tried through the available charsets on the mysql server but no proper result.
Has anyone experienced this issue before and can point me to the correct character set?

Comment: Bear in mind that just because a character is *displayed* as "Â„" doesn't mean that's how it's stored: undesirable conversion may have occurred between the database and your output medium.  The best way to verify that data is stored using the correct encoding is to fetch a hex representation of it with MySQL's [`HEX()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-functions.html#function_hex) function (and compare against that which one expects for the data).