# MySQL UTF8/ASCII/ISO Encoding Issue

Tags: mysql, encoding, ascii

I'm having an issue with encoding of a MySQL table.

**What I've Done**

1. The table is set to be **utf8_unicode_ci**
2. The columns are also set to be **utf8_unicode_ci** where needed
3. Setting "SET NAMES utf8" and the meta before viewing

**The Data/Problem**

The column in question (review) is copied and pasted from MS word.

- Have strings such as **Ã¢â‚¬â„¢** instead of '
- **PrÃªt Ã  Manger** which should read Pret a Manger
- other similar issues

**Ive Tried:**

```
UPDATE table_name SET col_name = CONVERT(CONVERT(CONVERT(col_name USING latin1) USING binary) USING utf8);
```

This cut's off the data. E.g "a nice review costing £10 and more". After running the above query, it gets turned into "a ncie review costing".

Any help/advice would be appreciated greatly.
Thanks,
Matt

Comment: I've got [a solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304485/how-to-detect-utf-8-characters-in-a-latin1-encoded-column-mysql) that might work for you. You mean "Prêt à Manger", and ‘ right?

Comment: thanks for your help but: MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows), with no changes

Comment: I think you have UTF-8 data that's being interpreted as Latin1, not the other way around.

Comment: php says it's utf8 but then why would it not display correctly in the browser if i've set all the headers?

Comment: PHP only says what it thinks it is, not what it actually is. When you see single characters expanding into multiple characters it's almost always a case of multi-byte UTF-8 characters being mis-interpreted as Latin1.

Answer (score 0):

To double check you have the correct utf8 settings try this:

1. Login to mysql and run  `mysql> show variables like 'char%';`

The output should look like:

```
     +--------------------------+---------------------------------+
     | Variable_name            | Value                           |
     +--------------------------+---------------------------------+
     | character_set_client     | utf8                            |
     | character_set_connection | utf8                            |
     | character_set_database   | utf8                            |
     | character_set_filesystem | binary                          |
     | character_set_results    | utf8                            |
     | character_set_server     | utf8                            |
     | character_set_system     | utf8                            |
     | character_sets_dir       | /usr/local/mysql/share/charsets/|
     +--------------------------+---------------------------------+
```

2. Then run `mysql> show variables like 'collation%';`

This should give you:

```
     +----------------------+-----------------+
     | Variable_name        | Value           |
     +----------------------+-----------------+
     | collation_connection | utf8_general_ci |
     | collation_database   | utf8_unicode_ci |
     | collation_server     | utf8_unicode_ci |
     +----------------------+-----------------+
```

If not edit your `/etc/my.cnf` or `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` if you an not find it just run `sudo find / -name my.cnf`

After you do find it do `vim /etc/my.cnf` press `i` to insert text and add

```
    [mysqld]
    collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
    init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
    character-set-server = utf8
```

Feel free to comment out the previous/old [mysqld] block or lines.

Save the file by pressing `esc` then type `:wq` and press `enter`

3. Restart mysql `service mysql restart` or `service mysqld restart`

Hope that helps.