# MySql database mixed character encoding in one column

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8, latin1

Due to some unfortunate prior events, one of our legacy databases has columns with `latin1` and `utf8` encoding mixed together, that is, several columns have data that might have both of the encodings, while the column default encoding is `latin1`. Is there a way to detect the encoding and convert them all to `utf8`

Comment: Dump the database, do `sed 's/DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1/DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci/'`, and import the file. Note that the conversion may be lossy if any of the columns contain characters that are not in *both* character sets.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1049958/4099592 This should help. You can run the queries and find out what encoding is where. Then you can run these queries to update them. `ALTER DATABASE databasename CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci; ALTER TABLE tablename CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;`

Comment: Thanks! I'm gonna look into these solutions one by one, also saw this script: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/910793/detect-encoding-and-make-everything-utf-8

Comment: There's this script on github https://github.com/nicjansma/mysql-convert-latin1-to-utf8 which i found out at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304485/how-to-detect-utf-8-characters-in-a-latin1-encoded-column-mysql answered by Patrick James McDougle which you can use to do the conversion.