# Easiest way to do unidecoding in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

In Python & Pandas there is an easy way to convert special characters to plain latin characters like below.

```
import pandas as pd
from unidecode import unidecode

df = pd.Series(['Ässät', 'Kärpät', 'Łódź'])
df.apply(unidecode)
```

This gives me

```
Out[7]: 
0     Assat
1    Karpat
2      Lodz
```

Is there any easy way to do the same in MySQL? I have only seen fairly complicated ways so far.

Comment: Can you include some sample use cases for MySQL that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Mysql's text manipulation functions are rather limited, you have to specify what characters to replace with what other characters.

Comment: [Thist topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304485/how-to-detect-utf-8-characters-in-a-latin1-encoded-column-mysql) may provide you with some guidance.