# mysql utf8mb4_general_ci issue

Tags: mysql, unicode

I have an issue with unicode chars in an utf8mb4_general_ci table

```
SELECT * FROM `t1` WHERE c1='musca'
```

returns

```
musca
muşca
muşcă
```

What I would like to know is if this is a bug - sounds like it;

and if it affects searching - it might, or better said it should; I can't make the column unique index

Anything I should do so mysql would consider **a** and **ă** and **s** and **ş** as different entities? (probably a and â, t and ţ, and i and î as well, but I haven't checked).

Should I store unicode chars as &#226 &#259 &#351 &#355 &#238 ?

I will need to retrieve the exact match of the user input.

Edited to add:

The answer is in the comments: I should collate the columns as utf8mb4_0900_as_cs as **Madhur Bhaiya** explained and demonstrated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting utf8 broken characters in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476356/detecting-utf8-broken-characters-in-mysql)

Comment: There are no broken chars though. Everything looks fine, except that if I try to make the column unique it's not possible, since per my example a = ă and s = ş

Comment: @flish What specific language do these characters belong to ? MySQL has added a lot of language specific collation recently.

Comment: @flish check this blog from MySQL team: https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-1-accent-and-case-sensitive-collations-for-utf8mb4/

Comment: @flish Check this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rV3EgJguKG97kXF28sFhmf/0 I used `utf8mb4_0900_as_cs` collation.

Comment: Thank you. I'll start on my reading. So is this question a duplicate? Should I click on the button and close it? EDITED to add: Also, these chars belong to Romanian, but I will need to add French and German as well and I thought general_ci would work for all.

Comment: @flish The _character set_ utf8 or utf8mb4 will work for all European languages.  A character set refers to the _encoding.  The longer things mentioned are _collations_; they refer to how to order the characters, such as wanting `a < ă` instead of `a = ă`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `COLLATION utf8_romanian_ci` (or utf8mb4_romanian_ci) on the table columns in question.  It is the only collation that treats those 5 characters as a separate 'letter'.

Reference:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/utf8_collations.html

That is available in most versions of MySQL/MariaDB.  There is no need for `utf8mb4_0900_as_cs`, which implies MySQL 8.0.

Comment: It works, yes and I've accepted it as the answer. I will still need to install MySQL 8 because the same table will also contain French and German characters and it won't work. I just checked é and e

Comment: @flish - I don't see the issue with `é`.  It collates equal to `e` in all collations except Icelandic for both MySQL 5 and 8.  I'm pretty sure the rest of French an German characters also work the same between 5 and 8.  Please elaborate.